# Binary operator '+=' connot be applied to operands of type '[Any]' and '[Int]'

Tags: swift, append

Why can't I append `testArray2`? I got the error **Binary operator '+=' connot be applied to operands of type '[Any]' and '[Int]'** when I did this:

```
var testArray : [Any] = [10,20,45,32]
var testArray2 : [Int] = [10,20,45,32]
var someArray : [Any] = []
someArray += testArray
someArray += testArray2
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is not the way [`+=`](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html) is defined:

```
func +=<T, C: CollectionType where C.Generator.Element == T>(inout lhs: [T], rhs: C)
```

The `where C.Generator.Element == T` part specifies that the types of the elements in the collection you're trying to add (`Int` in your case) must match *exactly* the types of the elements in the first array (`Any`).

Comment: But I can still append string in `someArray`, like this: `someArray += ["string2"]`

Comment: Because the compiler is smart enough to interpret that as an [Any]?